# 16-Bit RAW RGB_565 Image on Android

Tags: java, android, bitmap, rgb, 16-bit

I am trying to get a 16-bit color image that is 80 x 60 resolution from an embedded camera ([datasheet here](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/451/uCAM-DS-rev7-3555.pdf)). I am successfully able to get 9600 (80 * 60 * 16 / 8) bytes from the camera, but I have a problem displaying the image. I am using the following code to convert the byte array into a Bitmap:

```
bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(80, 60, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
bm.copyPixelsFromBuffer(ByteBuffer.wrap(jpegBytes));
```

jpegBytes is the array of the image's bytes and it is 9600 bytes long.

Right now, I am getting images that look like this:

[image: corrupted image]

99% of the time. However, I am able to get non-corrupted images that look like this:

[image: uncorrupted image]

very rarely. Does anyone have any suggestions as to why this is happening? Thanks so much!

UPDATE:

It seems like all the pixels are in the correct spot, but have their RGB values mixed up. For example, the white portion between both photos is the same because the order of RGB does not matter to get white. However, it is clear that the colors are mixed up because the red chair is showing up as blue in the corrupted image and the blue backpack is showing up as green in the corrupted image

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is because of your config Bitmap.Config.RGB_565.
Below is the extract from android documentation

> Each pixel is stored on 2 bytes and only the RGB channels are encoded: red is stored with 5 bits of precision (32 possible values), green is stored with 6 bits of precision (64 possible values) and blue is stored with 5 bits of precision. This configuration can produce slight visual artifacts depending on the configuration of the source. **For instance, without dithering, the result might show a greenish tint. To get better results dithering should be applied.** This configuration may be useful when using opaque bitmaps that do not require high color fidelity.

Hope this helps

Comment: The image does not have a greenish tint - all the pixels are severly discolored. I have already dithered the image and the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when uploading images to a watch.
[image: image1]

Turns out the bytes of each pixel were swapped. ie Red which is `0xF8 0x00` was loaded as `0x00 0xF8` thus showed up as a shade of Blue

```
val size = 115200   // (no of pixels * 2), 2 bytes per pixel (RGB_565)
val options = BitmapFactory.Options()
options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565
val image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(File(this.cacheDir, "image.png").path, options)    // load image as bitmap
val buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(size)
image.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer)
val byteArray = ByteArray(size)
for (x in 0 until size){
    val y = if (x%2 == 0){ x+1 } else { x-1 }   // added this to swap adjacent bytes
    byteArray[x] = buffer[y]        //copy to byteArray while swapping adjacent bytes
}
// finally, send byteArray to watch
```

[image: image 2]